# Flutter how to use Udemy API

Tags: flutter, dart, http-headers

i want to get courses from Udemy API using this code

```
Future<String> udemy() async {
try {
  dynamic response;
  String auth = base64.encode(utf8.encode('$Client_id:$Client_Secret'));
  final signUp = await http.get("https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/",headers: {"Authorization": auth});
  response = json.decode(signUp.body);
  print("RESPONSE FROM( udemy ){ ${response.toString()} }");
  return "Done";
} catch (e) {
  print("ERROR FROM( udemy ){ ${e.toString()} }");
  return "ERROR";
}
```

}

and i got this error

> detail: You do not have permission to perform this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you need to provide some form of authorization header or a bearer token which you need to login to get.

Have you gone through the docs here: https://www.udemy.com/developers/affiliate/

Comment: Sorry, reviewing the code I see that you are close but from their docs you have to pass something in this format:

```Authorization: Basic {BASE64_ENCODED(CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET)}```

Notice that you have this in your code:

`headers: {"Authorization": auth}`

Which doesn't indicate 'basic' like it needs to.  This is likely your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    Future<String> udemy() async {
try {
  dynamic response;
  String auth = base64.encode(utf8.encode('$Client_id:$Client_Secret'));
  final signUp = await http.get("https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/",headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + auth});
  response = json.decode(signUp.body);
  print("RESPONSE FROM( udemy ){ ${response.toString()} }");
  return "Done";
} catch (e) {
  print("ERROR FROM( udemy ){ ${e.toString()} }");
  return "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: thank you @john wiese it worked for me after adding "Basic"